# Python sees `json` module but pipenv doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, pip, pythonpath, pipenv

I am trying to help a coworker configure their VM. I am having a very strange problem:

```
Z:\codebase>pipenv uninstall
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies.
Locking [packages] dependencies.
nv\\resolver.py", line 3, in <module>
    import json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'json'


Z:\codebase>python
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> json
<module 'json' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\json\\__init__.py'>
>>>
```

So python can import json when I run it directly, but not when pipenv is running python. What could be causing this? Could pipenv be using an incorrect python path?

Comment: `json` is a standard library module. It should always be available. Your pipenv might be broken? Try reinstalling it.

Comment: check `pipenv --venv` output to see which python pipenv using, maybe `json` is deleted somehow