# Socketio installing problems

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, python-socketio

I'm facing a problem with socketio. I imported it into my programme by command:

> import socketio

Wen I typped pip freeze I got:

> python-socketio==4.5.1

Then I ran programme by typing into console:

> myfile.py --mode "mode"

But it says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socketio'

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try making a brand new virtual environment. Starting fresh usually solves these type of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you have multiple version of pip install on your system.

you can deal with this problem by creating a virtual environment and again loading the socket-io library.

Install pipenv.

```
pip install pipenv
```

Then change directory to the folder containing your Python project and initiate Pipenv,

```
cd your_project
pipenv install
```

This will build two new files in your project directory, Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, and a new virtual environment for your project, if it doesn't already exist. If you add the —two or —three flags to the last command above, your project will be initialized with the use of Python 2 or 3. Otherwise, Python's default version will be included.

To install a Python package for your project use the install keyword. For example,

```
pipenv install beautifulsoup4
```

and for uninstalling

```
pipenv uninstall beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: But what if it doesn't create Pipfile.lock ?

Comment: If you are facing the locking issue of pip file please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429542/pipenv-install-locking-failed-no-module-named-json